# WebView : Element type is invalid: expected a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

**My simple react code ;**

```
 import React from "react";
 import { Text, StyleSheet,View } from "react-native";
 import { WebView } from 'react-native';

 const App = () => {
    return(
      <WebView
        source={{
          uri: 'https://www.google.com/'
        }}
        style={{ marginTop: 20 }}
      />
    );
 }

 export default App;
```

**Error ;**

" Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.
(Device) "

Comment: As it says on the [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/webview.html) page, you're supposed to use the WebView from the `react-native-webview` package instead.

Comment: Correct. They have removed WebView from `react-native` and moved it into `react-native-webview` as of 0.60. Here is the [correct docs page](https://archive.reactnative.dev/docs/webview) in their archive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package you're trying to use is **deprecated**

You should use [react-native-webview](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview) instead